# How to identify a specific occurrence across two rows and calculate the count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have these 2 `pandas` dataframes:

```
id | userid | type 
1  | 20     | a  
2  | 20     | a
3  | 20     | b
4  | 21     | a  
5  | 21     | b
6  | 21     | a
7  | 21     | b
8  | 21     | b
```

I want to obtain the number of times 'b follows a' for each user, and obtain a new dataframe like this:

```
userid | b_follows_a
20     | 1
21     | 2
```

I know I can do this using `for` loop. However, I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shift()` to check if `a` is followed by `b` with vectorized `&` and then count the trues with a `sum`:

```
df.groupby('userid').type.apply(lambda x: ((x == "a") & (x.shift(-1) == "b")).sum()).reset_index()

#userid type
#0   20    1
#1   21    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Creative solution:

```
In [49]: df.groupby('userid')['type'].sum().str.count('ab').reset_index()
Out[49]:
   userid  type
0      20     1
1      21     2
```

Explanation:

```
In [50]: df.groupby('userid')['type'].sum()
Out[50]:
userid
20      aab
21    ababb
Name: type, dtype: object
```